# How to fix Error 213 in SQL Columns that ALL allow null

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I am having an issue with an sql query used in job automation

The procedure inserts data from a source table(48 columns) to destination table(49 columns where the 49th/last column is NOT in the source table). But **all columns in the destination and source table accept null**, so that shouldn't be an issue copying from 48 columns to 49 columns.

It throws this error :

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. [SQLSTATE 21S01] (Error 213).  The step failed.

It should just insert null into the 49th column and I have checked the column names and they correspond.

Let's treat this like I can't delete the 49th column.

Please what can I do here?

Comment: You could try to provide a `NULL` manually? Something like `INSERT INTO destination SELECT *, NULL FROM source`

Comment: You need to provide that how do you insert this record, use SQL task or use Mapping component, better provide your insert component UI.

Comment: Thank you, the manual insertion seems like a good idea. I did resolve it later on, found out that the procedure missed a column in the insert statement, but it's all good now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting `NULL` doesn't mean you can specify 49 cols and 48 values in the sql `INSERT` statement. The number of columns and number of values must match exactly. Either drop extra column from `INSERT` list or add 49th value (`NULL` I guess) to the values list. In both cases if column is NULLable, it will be set to `NULL`.

Comment: Actually, not true. NULL allows you the freedom of not specifying value in such column when inserting values.

Comment: " Either drop extra column from INSERT list or add 49th value (NULL I guess) to the values list. In both cases if column is NULLable, it will be set to NULL." -  which option is not true?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have code that's not working, you should post it so we can tell for sure what's happening. But I'd be pretty willing to bet you're trying to short cut the process and use something like this:

```
INSERT tableB
SELECT *
FROM tableA
```

But the tables don't have the same number of columns, so the SQL Engine doesn't know which source column goes into which destination column. You need to provide an explicit list so it knows which one you intend to ignore:

```
INSERT tableB 
(
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
  col48
)
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
  col48
FROM tableA;
```